# Pretty print Fortran dynamic type in gdb

Tags: fortran, gdb

Printing the values of Fortran allocatable polymorphic variables in gdb is very painful. Given the program below, in order to see the value of `alloc_ext`, I have to do the following:

```
(gdb) p alloc_ext
$1 = ( _data = 0x606260, _vptr = 0x400ce0 <__foo_MOD___vtab_foo_My_extended_type> )
(gdb) ptype alloc_ext
type = Type __class_foo_My_base_type_a
PTR TO -> (     Type my_base_type :: _data)
PTR TO -> (     Type __vtype_foo_My_base_type :: _vptr)
End Type __class_foo_My_base_type_a
(gdb) ptype alloc_ext%_data
type = PTR TO -> ( Type my_base_type
character*4 :: base_char
End Type my_base_type )
(gdb) p alloc_ext%_data
$2 = (PTR TO -> ( Type my_base_type )) 0x606260
(gdb) p *(my_extended_type*)(alloc_ext%_data)
$3 = ( my_base_type = ( base_char = 'base' ), extended_char = 'ext ' )
```

This quickly gets very painful if a derived type contains, say, an array of other polymorphic derived types. I've tried investigating the python pretty printing API, but I still can't seem to get hold of the actual dynamic type, or even the label on the `_vptr` address, which would be enough information to pretty print something.

I'm using gdb 8.0.1 and gfortran 7.2.1.

**MVCE:**

```
module foo
  implicit none

  type my_base_type
     character(len=4) :: base_char = "base"
  end type my_base_type

  type, extends(my_base_type) :: my_extended_type
     character(len=4) :: extended_char = "ext "
  end type my_extended_type

contains

  subroutine bar(arg)
    class(my_base_type), intent(in) :: arg

    print*, "breakpoint here"
    select type(arg)
    type is (my_base_type)
       print*, "my_base_type ", arg%base_char
    type is (my_extended_type)
       print*, "my_extended_type ", arg%base_char, " ", arg%extended_char
    end select
  end subroutine bar
end module foo

program mvce
  use foo
  implicit none

  type(my_base_type) :: base
  type(my_extended_type) :: ext
  class(my_base_type), allocatable :: alloc_base
  class(my_base_type), allocatable :: alloc_ext

  allocate(alloc_base, source=base)
  allocate(alloc_ext, source=ext)

  call bar(alloc_base)
  call bar(alloc_ext)
end program mvce
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a proof-of-concept that makes this a bit nicer: https://github.com/ZedThree/Fortran-gdb-pp. It's not perfect, but it does demonstrate a way of at least printing dynamic types and see their actual values 
 instead of just the `_data` and `_vptr` components. I've included the explanation from the README below.

---

### How does it work?

Unfortunately, we have to work around several limitations of the gdb
python API. Firstly, gdb reports the `dynamic_type` of a polymorphic
variable as being its base type, and not its actual dynamic type! This
means we need some other way of getting its dynamic type. Luckily, the
symbol for the `_vptr` component (at least with gfortran 7.2) contains
the dynamic type, so we can use this. Briefly, we do the following:

1. Look up symbol for the value's `_vptr`
2. Parse the symbol to get the dynamic type
3. Cast the `_data` component to a pointer to the dynamic type and
   dereference

For 1., we need to get the `_vptr` symbol. We can do this
in gdb with `info symbol foo%_vptr`. The python API lacks such a
function, so instead we do:

```py
gdb.execute("info symbol {:#x}".format(int(val['_vptr'])))
```

`int(val['_vptr'])` gets the address of `_vptr`

Next, we need to parse the symbol. With gfortran 7.2, `_vptr` symbols
look like either:

- `__<module name>_MOD___vtab_<module name>_<Dynamic type>` for types
  defined in modules, or
- `__vab_<program name>_<Dynamic type>.nnnn` for types defined in
  programs

Module and program names can contain underscores, but luckily the type
starts with a capital letter while everything else is in lower case.

Lastly, we need to actually print the `_data` component as the dynamic
type. While the python API does provide a `Value.cast(type)` method,
the `type` argument must be a `gdb.Type` object. No matter, we can use
the `gdb.lookup_type(name)` function... except that this doesn't work
with Fortran types. This time, we fallback to using
`gdb.parse_and_eval`:

```py
cast_string = "*({type}*)({address:#x})".format(
    type=real_type, address=int(val['_data']))
real_val = gdb.parse_and_eval(cast_string)
```

where `real_type` is a string containing the dynamic type. This
basically executes `*(<dynamic type>)(value%_data)` and then we can
pass the resulting value to a pretty printer that just returns
`str(val)`, i.e. like the default printer.